# Check if current user is logged in using any django social auth provider

Tags: django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I would like to check if a user is logged in via social authentication or using the django default authentication.

something like

if user.social_auth = true?

Comment: Long time, no workable answer...

Answer (score 4):

Ok after doing some research i came up with this solution to make sure if a user is authenticated using any social provider or just the default django auth. Check here for  [moreinfo..](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html#template-context-processors)

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated and not backends.associated %}

 #Do or show something if user is not authenticated with social provider but default auth

 {% elif user.is_authenticated and backends.associated %}

  #Do or show something if user is authenticated with social provider

 {% else %}

 #Do or show something if none of both

 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. I will try this method as well on tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

i was searching on that and the solution is **user.social_auth.exists()**
it will return True if the user exists in the database else it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth

try:
    UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
    print "user is logged in using the django default authentication"
else:
    print "user is logged in via social authentication"
```

You may to add a method to User model.

Answer (score 1):

From Python:

```
user.social_auth.exists()
```

will return `True` if user is social, `False` otherwise.

From template:

```
{% if not backends.associated %}
    <code if user is NOT social>
{% else %}
    <code if user is social>
{% endif %}
```

The `backends` context variable is automatically set in Django templates when you include the python-social-auth app in your Django project's config.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [django-social-auth](http://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) is deprecated. You can use [python-social-auth](http://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) instead.

In that case, you should use:

```
user.social_auth.filter(provider='BACKEND_NAME')
```

For instance, if current user is authenticated by Google Account:

```
if user.is_authenticated:
    if user.social_auth.filter(provider='google-oauth2'):
        print 'user is using Google Account!'
    else:
        print 'user is using Django default authentication or another social provider'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can query all the users that are using social authentication as follow, from UserSocialAuth app:

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth

if user in [u.user for u in UserSocialAuth.objects.all()]:
     #dosomething
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem to recognize social logged-in users by [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I should specify a separate tab for them in navigation bar to complete their profile page. Of course if a user has logged-in through social auth, no password has been set for him\her in DB. So I used `has_usable_password()` method [(django.contrib.auth)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/) for this propose. For exp:

```
{% if user.has_usable_password %}
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
{% elif not user.has_usable_password %}
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'set_pass' %}">Set password</a>
```

Obviously this tip will helpful as long as the user doesn't set password.