# Django: how to differenciate if the user is signing in from social_auth or local Django user

Tags: django, django-socialauth

Hi I am using Django "social-auth-app-django" package. I have two questions.

1. How to differentiate if the current user is from social media or local Django registered
2. How do we know that the current user is signed-in from which social media platform such as Google, FB or Twitter?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879011/check-if-current-user-is-logged-in-using-any-django-social-auth-provider

Answer (score 1):

You can depend on Django for that. Try something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import BACKEND_SESSION_KEY

last_auth_backend = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]

if last_auth_backend in [list of social backends]:
    print("user used social auth")
else:
    print("user used something else")
```